# Get bitmap from andengnine texture region

Tags: android, andengine

How do i get a `Bitmap` object from andengine's `TextureRegion` or `TextureAtlas`? I tried looking at all the methods in there but no luck at all.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more? Why do you need bitmap?

Comment: use the RenderTexture class of AndEngine, render your TextureRegion onto that RenderTexture and use the getBitmap method to retrieve a Bitmap.

Comment: @skjm, I got your answer! but if you could write and post as an example so that others could benefit... and i could up vote ya